# Is there a nice way to define an "object of 2-morphisms" in a 2-category?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, terminology

Given a 2-category $\mathcal{C}$ with $A,B \in \mathrm{Ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and $f,g \in \mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$, is there a nice (i.e, defined by a universal property) notion of an object $g^f$ of 2-morphisms from $f$ to $g$, with a definition analogous to an exponential object, or more generally an internal hom?

This seems like it would be a very natural sort of construction to want to have in a 2-category, but I can't figure out what the "right" way to define it is, or what this has been called (if anything) in the literature.

Of course, in the case of a strict 2-category, maybe the best thing we can  do is to simply look at the internal hom (if it exists) in each of the hom-categories. But I'm simply curious if we can additionally characterize a sort of "internal 2-hom object" rather than an "internal 2-hom 1-morphism".

Comment: My (somewhat naïve) first impression is that if such a thing were to exist, then it should exist when $\mathcal{C}=\mathbf{Cat}$, but that there isn't a particularly interesting *category* of natural transformations between any two given parallel functors. What motivated your question? Knowing the motivation might help with finding an answer.

Comment: @CliveNewstead, possibly relevant is that there's an inclusion $\mathbf{Set} \hookrightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ given by the notion of a discrete category, which allows us to view sets as special cases of categories.

Comment: @goblin: That's why I said there isn't a "particularly interesting" category ;) Relying on being able to think of exponential objects in $\mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$ as degenerate kinds of 0-cells of $\mathcal{C}$ seems to be essentially the same thing as what Nathan called a "internal 2-hom 1-morphism". But maybe there's something in it.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want here. $g^f$ is supposed to be an object of $C$? I'm having trouble coming up with a natural example of such a thing.

Comment: @CliveNewstead The example I had in mind was some sort of strict syntactical 2-category giving the semantics of a type theory with different computational rules. (so, objects are types, morphisms are terms, 2-morphisms are computation rules) So, in such a context, can we talk about an object of identity proofs between two terms?

Comment: I suppose essentially what I'm wondering is, what is the directed analogue of the categorical semantics of identity types in homotopy type theory?

Comment: And, beyond that, is the machinery of the homotopy interpretation of intensional type theory really necessary to define such an object categorically? Is there a more elementary way to do it?